# How to create a GET request for checked checkboxes and then display it on the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, checkbox, get

I'm creating an app for a project and I'm stuck with this feature. I've already created a POST method for the checked checkboxes but I don't know how to get that information and then display it on my HTML page. I'm not sure with my GET method.  It's basically an edit page feature. And we're only supposed to use AJAX and flask. Please help.

```
function edit_food() {
    console.log($('input[name="food"]:checked').serialize());

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/edit_food.html/',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (newSet) {
            $('input[name="food"]:checked');
            if (newSet.status == 'ok') {
                alert("SAVED!")
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });

   var $set = $('#set');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/food.html/',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (set) {
            $('input[name="food"]:checked');
            if (set.status == 'ok') {
                alert("SAVED!")
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Ajax, you can return data type string, json, or html.
I often return json data or html data.
With html data you can using:

```
.done(function(res){
    $('#id_reaload').html(res);
})
```

Comment: where do i put that?

Comment: Where you want reload view

Comment: Dev, the '#id_reaload' is where you want the display on the HTML page. The done function goes in your Ajax